# Creating multi-country Google Maps API Polygon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, polygon-creation

I'm working on an embedded interactive map using the Google Maps API. I need to show several "regions" that each contain some neighboring countries. For instance one of the regions is the countries of Afghanistan, Bahrain, Egypt, Iran, Iraq, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Lebanon, Oman, Pakistan, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Syria, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, United Arab Emirates, Uzbekistan and Yemen. I need a Google Maps Polygon (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple) that covers that combined area at the national borders.

**Is there any way to export the coordinates for a polygon that is made up of the outermost perimeter of a collection of countries?** I have just been downloading the individual countries from https://gadm.org/, converting the data to .kml files and trying to manually copy in the right coordinates but it's obviously very tedious.

This is my first Google Maps API project on this scale and I'm in a bit over my head. I've created custom and stylized embedded Google Maps on a city scale before.